# What happens to the difference in compatible buy and sell orders on bitcoin exchanges?

Tags: exchanges

Let's say Alice is selling 1 BTC for $10,000. Soon after Alice makes her sell order, Bob places a buy order for 1 BTC for $10,010. These two orders are compatible, since Alice would gladly take an extra $10.

My question is, what happens to that $10.

- Does Alice receive $10,010 even though her sell order was only for $10,000?
- Does Bob only have to pay $10,000?
- Maybe they split it down the middle, Bob only has to pay $10,005 and Alice receives the same?
- Does the exchange just keep the difference? Is this how (in addition to the fees) exchanges profit?

Comment: Short answer: Bob pays $10,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you:

> Does Alice receive $10,010 even though her sell order was only for
>   $10,000?

No, Alice will receive $10,000 only

> Does Bob only have to pay $10,000?

Yes

> Maybe they split it down the middle, Bob only has to pay $10,005 and
>   Alice receives the same?

No, that is not how an exchange works. The largest bid get's filled first. And the smallest sell order get's filled first.

> Does the exchange just keep the difference? Is this how (in addition
>   to the fees) exchanges profit?

No, the exchange is only entitled to get fees for the transaction unless specified otherwise.